# Hidden Viewpart in Eclipse RCP with iFolderLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an Eclipse (3.X) RCP application. I am trying to implement a way to have a ViewPart display in a pre-defined placeholder (IFolderLayout). But here is the problem, whenever I initially launch the application the placeholder is displayed as a dark grayed out area in the application. I do not want that placeholder displayed when my application launches. I would only like the ViewPart to appear were the placeholder is when I call it. I have looked high and low for a way to do this. I know that since the IFolderLayout is not durable it closes when the ViewPart is closed. This is a desired effect, but I do not want the IFolderLayout to display when I launch the application. My code is being created in the overridden `createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout)` method

To clarify: Imagine I have a view that takes up the entire screen. When I click on a button another ViewPart appears on the bottom half pushing the original view up to make room for the new ViewPart so they are both equally displayed. I do not want the IFolderLayout placeholder displayed when the application launches.

Here is my placeholder code:

```
IFolderLayout bottomHalf = layout.createFolder(args here);
bottomHalf.addPlaceHolder(BottomHalfView.ID);
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `layout.createFolder()`, call `layout.createPlaceholderFolder()`, with the same arguments, but a different return type.

```
IPlaceholderFolderLayout bottomHalf = layout.createPlaceholderFolder( ... );
bottomHalf.addPlaceHolder(BottomHalfView.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks... that worked halfway. I still have the issue were if I launch the application in a different perspective and switch to the perspective with this in it the box appears. But when I launch the application in the perspective with this in it, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Odd. One thing you could try would be to delete the configuration directories (which may be specified by -Dosgi.configuration.area and -Dosgi.instance.area), to ensure nothing has been persisted from prior runs with the former perspective layout.

Comment: Ok it works now! But the view is now appearing on top of the original view instead of below it, even though I have it set to appear blow it...  

        layout.createPlaceholderFolder(BottomId, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.70f, TopId)

Comment: Problem is now fixed! Thanks for your solution! I'll up it as soon as I am allowed to!